How do I change Firefox's cache to /dev/shm?
I went into about:config and added browser.cache.disk.parent_directory as /dev/shm/firefox but nothing is appearing in the directory. firefox doens't even show.
I've restarted the browser, visited websites. Nothing's in the shm directory.

provide the exact line please. browser.cache.disk.parent_directory = /dev/shm/ works for an APT version of FF. NOTHING behind shm/. firefox-cachewill be created in/dev/shm/`

I've got the snap version. Does that make a difference?

Snap Firefox cannot access /dev/shm, only /home.
